# How to customize the TemporalAdjusters in Java 8?

Tags: datetime, time, calendar, java-8, localdate

I am working with Java 8 Date and Time utility. I am using the [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) interface and the implementations found in [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) to manipulate the calculations for a specific day or date.

My requirement is to calculate the day after 3 month and 2 days.
For example, today is 6th of Decemeber (i.e 2016-12-06 in YYYY-MM-DD) and after 3 months and 2 days, the date would be 8th of March, 2017 (i.e. 2017-03-08 in YYYY-MM-DD).

I tried two ways of doing this using the Date and Time utility as follows:

```
//First
LocalDate dayAfter3MonthsAnd2Days = LocalDate
    .now()
    .with(firstDayOfNextMonth()).plusMonths(2).plusDays(2);

//Second
LocalDate dayAfter3MonthsAnd2Days = LocalDate
    .now()
    .with(firstDayOfMonth()).plusMonths(3).plusDays(2);
```

Both of them returns the date as 3rd of March, 2017 (i.e. 2017-03-03) as follows:

> dayAfter3MonthsAnd2Days = 2017-03-03

Is there any way i can customize the TemporalAdjusters and get the desired output? Or any other alternate to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that i can simply use the following:

```
LocalDate dayAfter3MonthsAnd2DaysNew = LocalDate
                                            .now()
                                            .plusMonths(3)
                                            .plusDays(2);
```

Alongwith that, i can also use the custom TemporalAdjuster which uses the above same process to do manipulations as follows:

```
TemporalAdjuster ta = TemporalAdjusters.ofDateAdjuster(
                                         (LocalDate d) -> d.plusMonths(3).plusDays(2));

LocalDate dayAfter3MonthsAnd2DaysCustom = LocalDate
                                                .now()
                                                .with(ta);
```

Although the previous way is simpler, but we can use more custom proceedings using ofDateAdjuster method of TemporalAdjuster.

Comment: Yes, customizing of existing adjusters is not possible. It is just a formalized way to write some helper code. So the conclusion is: Not customizing but writing a new adjuster. And it is still your task to write the real implementation as done in your answer.

Comment: Good Question and Answer, informative. As an aside: Better to explicitly pass a `ZoneId` to the `now` method rather than rely implicitly on the JVM’s current default time zone that can change at any moment during runtime. Example: `LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )`